# Angular and Visual Studio C# mvc projects

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

I started learning angular and mastered the basics. I am C# developer. I am trying to see how an mvc project can be implemented with Angular.  I am not reaching anywhere because I cannot wrap my mind around it.

Can  razor syntax be used with angular or it wouldn't work?

I am not very clear how to map an Visual studio C# mvc view to a angular html file...
Any simple examples out there? Anybody could give me some guidance please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it looks overcomplicated as example but it really helps me in big project.

Basic idea is create a module for dedicated feature and use redux library to manage data source and commands

Redux library documentation you can read here [here](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/intro)

Simple example you can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fcontainers%2Fgrid-data%2Fgrid-data.component.ts)

[Top level component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fcontainers%2Fgrid-data%2Fgrid-data.component.ts) connect underlying [view component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fcomponents%2Fgrid-view%2Fgrid-view.component.ts) with [model](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fservices%2Fmodel.service.ts) and  [controller](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fservices%2Fcontroller.service.ts).

Redux things implemented in ['state'](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fstate%2Ftable.state.ts) folder.

All parts combined into [TableModule](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Ftable.module.ts) and included into [main module](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts).

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help..How do you plug all these things in a Visual Studio MVC application?

Comment: @Sam you can fork it or clone https://github.com/rnrn/Angular-MVC